# OpenMP and memory bandwidth restriction

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp, memory-bandwidth

Edit: My first code sample was wrong. Fixed with a simpler.

I implement a C++ library for algebraic operations between large vectors and matrices.
I found on x86-x64 CPUs that OpenMP parallel vector additions, dot product etc are not going so faster than single threaded.
Parallel operations are -1% - 6% faster than single threaded.
This happens because of memory bandwidth limitation (I think).

So, the question is, is there real performance benefit for code like this:

```
void DenseMatrix::identity()
{
    assert(height == width);
    size_t i = 0;
    #pragma omp parallel for if (height > OPENMP_BREAK2)
    for(unsigned int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        for(unsigned int x = 0; x < width; x++, i++)
            elements[i] = x == y ? 1 : 0;
}
```

In this sample there is no serious drawback from using OpenMP.
But if I am working on OpenMP with Sparse Vectors and Sparse Matrices, I cannot use for instance *.push_back(), and in that case, question becomes serious. (Elements of sparse vectors are not continuous like dense vectors, so parallel programming has a drawback because result elements can arrive anytime - not for lower to higher index)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a problem of memory bandwidth. I see clearly a problem on `r`: `r` is accessed from multiple threads, which causes both *data races* and *false sharing*. False sharing can dramatically hurt your performance.

I'm wondering whether you can get even the correct answer, because there are data races on `r`. Did you get the correct answer?

However, the solution would be very simple. The operation conducted on `r` is *reduction*, which can be easily achieved by `reduction` clause of OpenMP.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88b1k8y5(v=vs.80).aspx

Try to simply append `reduction(+ : r)` after `#pragma omp parallel`.

(Note: Additions on `double` are not commutative and associative. You may see some precision errors, or some differences with the result of the serial code.)